# Linked List Stack Question in Regards to the Stack Being Empty

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I am worked on a Linked list stack and a bunch of functions for it. What I do not understand currently is how come my "isEmpty" function is not working correctly. I believe that the way I have it written makes sense. By nature if Front is Null then the list should have to be empty which would mean that "isEmpty" would return false. The problem that I am having is that my program says that the list is always empty whether or not it actually is or not. I am not sure what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
}*front = NULL, *rear = NULL, *p = NULL, *np = NULL;
void push(int x)
{
    np = new node;
    np->data = x;
    np->next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL)
    {
        front = rear = np;
        rear->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = np;
        rear = np;
        rear->next = NULL;
    }
}
int pop()
{
    int x;
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"empty queue\n";
    }
    else
    {
        p = front;
        x = p->data;
        front = front->next;
        delete(p);
        return(x);
    }
}

int peek()
{
    int x;
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"empty queue\n";
    }
    else
    {
        p = front;
        x = p->data;
        front = front->next;
        return(x);
    }
}

bool isEmpty()
{
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (front != NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void Display()
{
cout << front;
}

int main()
{
    int n, c = 0, x;
    bool is_empty = isEmpty();
    cout<<"Enter the number of values to be pushed into queue\n";
    cin>>n;
    while (c < n)
    {
    cout<<"Enter the value to be entered into queue\n";
    cin>>x;
        push(x);
        c++;
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Pop value: ";

    if (front != NULL)
            cout<<pop()<<endl;

    cout<<endl<<"Peak value: ";

    if (front != NULL)
            cout<<peek()<<endl;

    if (is_empty == true)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"The list is empty";
    }
    else if (is_empty == false)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"The list is not empty";
    }


    cout << endl << "The current contents of the stack are: ";
while(front != NULL)
{
    Display();
    if(front == NULL)
        cout << "The stack is empty";
    break;
}
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What do you think `is_empty` does?

Comment: You set `is_empty` 1 time at the beginning of your `main()` it does not change its value after regardless of the condition of the stack. Instead call `isEmpty()` each time you want to check.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you that was very helpful.

Comment: @drescherjm do you also know why this code does not properly display the contents of the list and only displays the list if the list is empty.

Comment: Did you put at least 2 items in the stack? `if (front != NULL) cout<<pop()<<endl;` removes the first item if there is one.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes I did, if the stack is empty it will spit out zero. However if its not it just spits out random stuff. I know that pop kills off the top item. Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @FeiXiang I will look into the formatting, thank you for the help

Comment: I can tell you that `void Display()` is wrong. Or at least it does not show the item that is at the head.

Comment: Remember that all your `Display()` function does is print out the *pointer* (it doesn't print the value of the node and it also doesn't move the pointer to the next node). Also, format your code properly and you'll find another bug in that loop.

Comment: There is a missing scope in the else that causes it to break always because the break is not part of the else.

Comment: @drescherjm I don't think that is the issue because if the stack is actually empty it will say that is but when it is not it will saying something like the current contents are : 0xe11360

Comment: `0xe11360` is caused by the wrong implementation of `Display()` @FeiXiang mentioned what you have it doing. The missing scope causes it to print only 1 time. Then there is also no moving to the next node for display. Not sure how you want to handle that. I think Display should be totally rewritten and the while(true) loop removed.

Comment: @drescherjm Hmm I guess I am confused on what you mean then. I changed the code to this:

Comment: @drescherjm In the above code, do you mean something like that

Comment: I think Display should be totally rewritten and the while(true) loop in main removed.  I have to go now.

Comment: @drescherjm rewritten again from when I just did it and edited the code above or no

Comment: @drescherjm I think part of the problem stems from when I call display no matter what it displays some form of random stuff even outside the loop. like I just tried it and I get 0x11e1360

Comment: `cout << front;` prints the address of the pointer of your head node not its data

Comment: @drescherjm Ohh that makes sense, how would you make it print its data out then

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code.

You have defined an `isEmpty()` function, but you don't really it.  You have declared a separate variable `is_empty` that you set to the return value of `isEmpty()` one time before you populate the list, and never update `is_empty` after making any changes to the list.  That is why your code is always reporting the list is "empty" even if it is really not.  You need to get rid of the `is_empty` variable and call `isEmpty()` every time you need to check for empty.

Also, the return value of `peek()` and `pop()` are *indeterminate* if `front` is NULL.

And `peek()` pops the `front` node from the list.  Only `pop()` should be doing that.

And `pop()` does not check if `rear` is pointing at the node being popped. You are not resetting `rear` to NULL in that case.

And you don't free any nodes remaining in the list before exiting the program.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;

    node(int value): data(value), next(NULL) {}
};

node *front = NULL;
node *rear = NULL;

void push(int x)
{
    node **np = (rear) ? &(rear->next) : &front;
    *np = new node(x);
    rear = *np;
}

int peek()
{
    if (front)
        return front->data;
    return -1;
}

int pop()
{
    int x = peek();

    if (front)
    {
        node *p = front;
        front = front->next;
        if (p == rear) rear = NULL;
        delete p;
    }

    return x;
}

bool isEmpty()
{
    return !front;
}

void clear()
{
    while (front)
    {
        node *p = front;
        front = front->next;
        delete p;
    }
    rear = NULL;
}

void display()
{
    node *n = front;
    if (n)
    {
        cout << n->data;
        while (n = n->next)
            cout << ' ' << n->data;
    }
}

int askForNumber(const char *prompt)
{
    int n;
    cout << prompt << ": ";
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int n, x;

    n = askForNumber("Enter the number of values to be pushed into queue");

    for(int c = 0; c < n; ++c)
    {
        x = askForNumber("Enter the value to be entered into queue");
        push(x);
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Pop value: ";
    if (!isEmpty())
        cout << pop();
    else
        cout << "empty queue";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Peak value: ";
    if (!isEmpty())
        cout << peek();
    else
        cout << "empty queue";
    cout << endl;

    if (isEmpty())
        cout << "The list is empty";
    else
        cout << "The list is not empty";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The current contents of the stack are:" << endl;
    display();
    cout << endl;

    clear();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```